# Order 'select' entries with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I was wondering how I'd go about having a select box with a height of perhaps 4 or 5, with an up and down arrow next to it to order the entries? Thing is, I need to draw the entries from a database with PHP, order them with the box, then submit them back to the database. So it can't just be an aesthetic change, its got to actually change the ID of them? Is this possible?

Cheers,
BlackWraith

**~EDIT~**
This is the code I want to use, I just want to be able to rearrange the entries and record the new order of the entries.

```
<select size="4">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='6'>6</option>
    <option value='7'>7</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Up">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Down">
```

Comment: It's probably possible but what have you tried so far? Any code?

Comment: @elclanrs: Not yet, I have no idea where to start with this.

Comment: i think using an array can help you you can refer this site, http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml i have not tried any but you can start from here and work on some stuff then we could go deep into your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it a little more fancy using the ready-made jQuery UI Sortable control: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Comment: I like jQuery, and I would have used this, except my list is going to have up to almost 40 entries, and dragging them round will be a nightmare :/

Comment: Sorry for the realllllllly late reply, but I forgot to get back to it. This worked wonderful, thankyou for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?
http://jsfiddle.net/DKCtV/1/

As an example, do not know what kind of select box you have

```
<div><input type='text' value='1' name='field[]' />
     <span class='up'>Up</span><span class='down'>Down</span></div>
<div><input type='text' value='2' name='field[]' />
     <span class='up'>Up</span><span class='down'>Down</span></div>
<div><input type='text' value='3' name='field[]' />
     <span class='up'>Up</span><span class='down'>Down</span></div>
<div><input type='text' value='4' name='field[]' />
     <span class='up'>Up</span><span class='down'>Down</span></div>
<div><input type='text' value='5' name='field[]' />
     <span class='up'>Up</span><span class='down'>Down</span></div>
<div><input type='text' value='6' name='field[]' />
     <span class='up'>Up</span><span class='down'>Down</span></div>
<div><input type='text' value='7' name='field[]' />
     <span class='up'>Up</span><span class='down'>Down</span></div>
```

and jquery code

```
$('.up').css('cursor','pointer').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('div').insertBefore($(this).parents('div').prev());
});

$('.down').css('cursor','pointer').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('div').insertAfter($(this).parents('div').next());
});
```

another solution is to move only the values, not the tags  :))
http://jsfiddle.net/a3HV7/2/

```
$('.up').css('cursor','pointer').click(function(){
  var prev = $(this).parents('div').prev().find('input'), oldval = prev.val();
  prev.val($(this).siblings('input').val());
  $(this).siblings('input').val(oldval);
});

$('.down').css('cursor','pointer').click(function(){
  var next = $(this).parents('div').next().find('input'), oldval = next.val();
  next.val($(this).siblings('input').val());
  $(this).siblings('input').val(oldval);
});
```

Comment: Hey, looks good, but not quite what I'm after. Looking for something more like this sort of thing, but with functionality; http://jsfiddle.net/DKCtV/1/

Comment: @BlackWraith Show an example. If you want to replace input with select - no problem at all. Just keep the name of the select as array name='some_name[]'. Or do you have something else? Change of IDs could be done the same way as moving values at the last example.

Comment: What I'm trying to aim for is what you've done with individual input boxes, all inside the one select. So I can rearrange entries inside the single select box. Is this possible? I know I've seen it a while back, but I can't think where, or what to search for to look for an example.

Comment: @BlackWraith So, do you have an open select with possible multiple selections? and you want just to move it options up and down? What information about the order of the elements will be submitted to the server?

Comment: nope, just single selections only, and just up and down, and just the positions of them.

Comment: `all inside the one select. So I can rearrange entries inside the single select box. Is this possible?` show the code, please. If you want to see all the options in the select it should be open.

Comment: @BlackWraith How do you image to do it with standard select tag ?:) you have select at first what you want to move. But when you are moving this option, what are you going to see in closed select? Do you have a code that will take the order and send to the server? By default only one value, selected, is sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an example of that very thing as part of my "ObCollectionOrdered" component (basically an array abstraction that makes it simple to manage collections of ordered objects):

http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_obcollectionordered/

The example is here:

http://home.comcast.net/~kiwidust/JSExtensions/DP_ObCollectionOrdered/Example1.htm

It basically just loads the "option" objects into a collection - which gives you very simple access to do all sorts of movement and sorting on them.  Then there's a simple function to redraw the select.

The "order of the entries" is kept in the collection for access at any time.

Most of the form frameworks have this built-in if you're already using one - but if you want to add it quickly to vanilla code this should do the trick.  If you need something even simpler you can always strip the unneeded stuff from this component.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks quite promising, I shall try and work with it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use the jQuery 'sortable' function. Thanks to everyone who helped out